# how identify first anchor tag in sass in a class?

Tags: html, css, sass

Suppose the following snippet

```
<div class="class-a">
   <a href="#">Hello</a>
   <ul>
     <li>
       <a href="#">Hello A</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#">Hello B</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

how select a tag which contains hello text by sass in class-a. please help me.

Comment: You wan't to select a either text Hello A or Hello B in your class-a?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

**SCSS**

```
$colors: red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple;

@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {
  li:nth-child(#{length($colors)}n+#{$i}) {
    background: lighten(nth($colors, $i), 20%);
  }
}
```

checkout the live : https://codepen.io/cimmanon/full/yoCDG/

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.

CSS (what Sass compiles into) is a presentation language, it has no knowledge of the content of the page.

The best option would be to decorate all the fields you want styled with a css class and then just use that css class.

If you want to set these classes via JQuery, I think the code you're looking for is this:
`$('a:contains("Hello")').addClass('helloStyle');`

As ewcz commented, here is a link to a duplicate question.
[Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text)